# Core Bluetooth Central Connection Latency XCode

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

I am using the `CoreBluetooth.framework` framework to transfer data to a peripheral, and my Macbook Pro is the central. It is working, but there is a 2 second delay between each send, and I have been advised to increase the latency.

I have found the following instance method in the CBPeripheralManager class, but since I am not acting as a peripheral I don't think I can access it, since I use CBCentralManager because I am a central, and CBCentralManager does not have this instance method.

```
(void)setDesiredConnectionLatency:(CBPeripheralManagerConnec‌​tionLatency)latency forCentral:(CBCentral *)central
```

In sum, I am looking for a way to increase latency when acting as the central. I do not have access to the code of the peripheral I am looking for a way to change it on the central.

Comment: You can't change it on the central. Only the peripheral can request a different latency.

Comment: @Paulw11 Maybe I am looking in the wrong direction, my goal is to speed up the transfer of data. When I use a CSR 4.0 dongle instead of internal Bluetooth it fires every 1.3 seconds whereas the internal Bluetooth is every 2.5 seconds and I am surprised there is this much discrepancy.